# How can I get the first character from this string in c?

Tags: c

I have two strings
`char name1[100], name2[100];`
I want to concatenate the first letters of these strings. How can I do it?
I want to do it with the function strcat.
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiOeE.jpg)

Comment: The first *letter* from *each* string? And put them... where... exactly? This question is *screaming* for expected input and output examples, and frankly something more than two variable declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the trick in this question?

```
char conc[3];
conc[0] = name1[0];
conc[1] = name2[0];
conc[2] = '\0';
```

Or using the same array:

```
  name1[1] = name2[0];
  name1[2] = '\0';
```

---

### UPDATE

Using strcat:

```
name1[1] = '\0';
name2[1] = '\0';
strcat(name1,name2);
```

Comment: Where does the OP says about a third variable?

Comment: I want to use strcat.

Comment: @Michi where does he say he can't?

Comment: @ManuelPozosHernández `name1[1] = 0; name2[1] = 0; strcat(name1, name2);`

Comment: @EOF Thanks for your help!